# indent configurations in emacs cider/paredit/clojure-mode

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, paredit

In an Emacs/Cider setup (which is build on top of clojure-mode and paredit-mode), tab stops are usually ignored. Or, say they indent just to the second symbol of an s-expression.

Sometimes, e.g for larger configurations, it's desirable to indent also the subsequent symbols:

This would be the default:

```
(def config [:hello 34 :goodbye
             :a 34 :c
             :long-word 0 :a])
```

What is to do, if it should look like:

```
(def config [:hello      34   :goodbye
             :a          34   :c
             :long-word  0    :a])
```

Comment: Is your config a vector? If it is map, [clojure-align](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode#vertical-alignment) should do the job.

Comment: nice, this is good for maps. But actually I need it for vectors as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs will not align the elements in vector as you wish, however, you can use `M-i` (`tab-to-tab-stop`) to insert tab (or multiple spaces depends on your config). So you can manually align the elements like the way you like.

Comment: that's good to have! It would be even better if clojure-align was enhanced to work with any collection. https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/464c9de6734cb4b426137674041d695c2a7c7ef9/clojure-mode.el#L973

Comment: Feel free to file a ticket. We didn't consider such an usecase, but we might implement it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with having your config as a map instead of a vector, clojure-mode does the right thing when you switch on `clojure-align-forms-automatically`:

```
(def config {:hello 34
             :goodbye [something else]
             :a [34 :c]
             :long-word 0
             :a 'b})

=>

(def config {:hello     34
             :goodbye   [something else]
             :a         [34 :c]
             :long-word 0
             :a         'b})
```